# Plotly cannot save interactive graph to html file anymore

Tags: python, html, plot, plotly, interactive

I have a problem with saving interactive plotly graphs for later presentation. When I execute my code in the spyder editor I routinely get a graph opened in my browser that appears normal and has all the interactive features.

However when I want to save my plot using write_html() I get a file that I cannot open in any browser (be it chrome, edge or firefox).

This already happens with a simple example like

```
    import plotly.express as px
    fig =px.scatter(x=range(10), y=range(10))
    fig.write_html(home + "file.html")
```

To mention, with an older PC of mine I got wonderful html files that worked perfect with all interactive features.

I wonder if this could be a problem of the tool used for generating the plot. So far I have used orca & kaleido. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Thanks to you wonderful people

P.S.: I work with plotly version 5.1.0 under windows 10 and use spyder 5 for running my code.

Comment: Which versions of OS/plotly are you using? I don't get this problem in Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6, plotly 5.5.0. Also `home` is not a valid variable in your example (unless you have defined it outside of your example).

Comment: Also tested with Ubuntu 20.04, Python 3.8.10, plotly 5.5.0. Works fine.

Comment: I am working on windows 10 and my plotly version is 5.1.0, so the newest.
Yeah home is a valid path, I already stored there the png version of my plots which seem to work fine

Answer (score 0):

Since you're mentioning an older PC, I'll bet you've got a newer version of Plotly installed on your new system. This means that that you should use Kaleido instead with:

```
pip install -U kaleido
```

Or:

```
conda install -c plotly python-kaleido
```

And then you should be good to go with:

```
graph.write_image("name_of_file.jpeg")
```

Comment: I was also wondering if this might have been the problem, but isn't kaleido just for exporting static (non-interactive) graphs? At least that's how I understood it from their documentation.
Anyway, kaleido also does not work, even when deinstalling orca additionally.